# Is there a way to force any links to open in the same window of the chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

Do you know a way to open any links in the same window of the Chrome web browser instead of opening them in a new window?

FYI, the below methods don't work all the time:

1. Holding **Ctrl+mouse-left-click** doesn't work for all kinds of links.
2. "**Open link in the same tab, pop-up as tab**" chrome extension doesn't work on some links.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to drag and drop the link in the address bar.